# numpy filtering 2D

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have a sample 2D np array as follows:

```
x = np.random.normal(loc = -1, scale = 0.2, size = (100, 2))

x.shape
# (100, 2)

# Visualizing the distribution:
plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to filter values:
select all values along x-axis less than or equal to -1.3 and all values along y-axis less than or equal to -0.9. Basically, capture the 4 points within the box in the lower left side of the figure.

This is the code I have:

```
x[x[:, 0] <= -1.3, x[:, 1] <= -0.9]
```

But this gives the error:

> IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension
> 1; dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 100

Comment: The error message says it: you are trying to access the array `x` at indexes that are boolean expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine two boolean masks using the element-wise product and then index `x` with it:

```
>>> x[(x[:, 0] <= -1.3)*(x[:, 1] <= -0.9)]
array([[-1.41242713, -1.0017676 ],
       [-1.30424828, -1.20114282],
       [-1.3234422 , -1.29396616]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try just adding the operator for and `&` as follows:

```
x[(x[:, 0] <= -1.3) & (x[:, 1] <= -0.9)]
```

Comment: The correct code should be ```x[(x[:, 0] <= -1.3) & (x[:, 1] <= -0.9)]```. Your code gives the error: "TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"